# Convertir Tabla en Maestro Detalle Sql Server

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, ssis

Extraje un archivo Plano a una Tabla.

El archivo tiene identificadores para el Encabezado y Detalle.

Todas las P son Encabezado
Todas las I son detalle

El problema es que no hay nada que las una.

Como puedo separarlas en 2 tablas generando un id para poder ligarlas.

Lo único que encontré es. . .

Los registros de tipo P tienen un consecutivo, en el campo SequenceNumber
pero los tipo I no tienen esa referencia.

Las filas de tipo P, Tienen un campo que dice cuantos registros de tipo I le corresponden. En el campo NumberOfItems.

Como puedo ponerle el SequenceNumber a las Filas de tipo I? para separarlas en Maestro/Detalle?

Adjunto una imagen para que se aprecie que las filas están ordenadas, siempre hay una P seguida de las I que son su detalle. Y así sucesivamente.

[image: SQL]

Comment: ¿Qué comando estás utilizando para mostrarlas en ese orden? Si no estás utilizando ningún comando, ¿podrías indicarnos desde qué programa estás mostrando las filas en ese orden?

Comment: No estoy utilizando ningún comando, así están alojadas en la tabla por default. Las inserté con Integration Services. Y están ordenadas asi. Todas las P van seguidas de las I que le corresponden.

Comment: Imagino que debe venir de algun tipo de host antiguo, tipo AS400 o similar. Ahi se suelen utilizar ficheros de texto con diferentes tipos de registro separando los campos con algun caracter especial, o simplemente ocupando cada campo x posiciones o caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

Yo crearía primero las dos tablas destino, cabecera y detalle. En la tabla detalle tendrás que acordarte de crear un campo que referencie a la clave primaria de la cabecera (es decir, una clave foránea o *foreign key*)

Después depende un poco de que BBDD hablemos pero podrías hacer un cursor que recorra tu tabla y haga inserts en una u otra tabla en función de lo que vayas encontrando. En el cursor podrás almacenar datos en variables y por ejemplo podrás hacer cosas como:

```
Para cada registro de tu tabla origen

Si el registro es P
    BEGIN
        Inserto el registro en cabecera y su ID es <valorDelID>
    END
sino
    BEGIN
        Inserto el registro en linea con la clave foranea <valorDeID>
    END
fin si

Siguiente registro
```

Comment: Gracias, estoy usando SQL Server, voy a ver eso de los cursores, quería hacerlo con SSIS pero puedo hacerlo con un sp e invocarlo desde ssis y ya